# How can I find the version of my Chef server

Tags: centos, chef-infra

I am unsure what version of chef server is installed. How can I find this version?

Comment: Do you have access to the server via SSH, via web interface? Details, please!

Answer (score 0):

`chef-server-ctl version` should show it. You can also check your packaging system (deb, rpm, etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
To check chef-client version 
=> chef -v 
will get the details of 
-> chef dk version
-> chef-client version
-> delivery version
-> berks version
-> kitchen version
-> inspecific version
```